# Amazon Connect date calculations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I am writing a call flow in Amazon Connect.  I am using Lex to get a date from the caller into a slot and then setting a call attribute in Connect equal to the value of the slot.  I need to calculate how many years have passed between the date the caller provides and today.

Can this be done within Connect and if yes, how?  Or do I need to write a Lambda function?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do this in a lambda function, as there is no access to date time functions or ad-hoc programatic mechanisms within the Amazon Connect contact flow blocks (actions). The contact flow blocks only provides a set of comparison operators to compare contact attribute or metrics within the blocks.

You could potentially invoke this lambda function from within Lex, so that the slot data is returned as the time difference that you need, or call it from the contact flow after you get the Lex slot data with the captured date. Either way, it would need to be done in lambda.

Comment: Completely agree, when you think of "I need to calculate", "I need to change", "I need to look up", "I need to Call" think Lambda